# Set sepwidth heatmap.2 (gplots)

Tags: r

I am trying to increase sepwidth betweeen rows and columns in my heatmap.
I use sepwidth, however when i try to increase sepwidth, it does not move columns or rows to right.

Here is an example

```
library(gplots)
mat = matrix( rnorm(100), ncol=5 )
colorside = gray(1:5/5)
bk1 = seq(min(mat),max(mat),length.out=11)
col = redgreen(10)

# And now the heatmap
heatmap.2( mat, 
           key=FALSE, 
           trace="none",
           ColSideColors=colorside,
           cexRow=0.6,
           breaks=bk1,
           col=col,
           sepwidth=c(0.4,0.4),
           sepcolor="purple",
           colsep=1:ncol(mat),
           rowsep=1:nrow(mat))
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand what you want. Anyway my guess is that you want to add space before the first column and above the first row.

`sepwidth` defines the amount of space between columns and rows, and applies that space based on the values in the vectors `colsep` and `rowsep`. In your case, you simple have to start one unit earlier in the definitions of `colsep` and `rowsep`, like in the following code:

```
setseed(8765) ## added for reproducibility

# Your code
library(gplots)
mat = matrix( rnorm(100), ncol=5 )
colorside = gray(1:5/5)
bk1 = seq(min(mat),max(mat),length.out=11)
col = redgreen(10)

## First call to get "hm1"
hm1 <- heatmap.2( mat, 
                 key=FALSE, 
                 trace="none",
                 ColSideColors=colorside,
                 cexRow=0.6,
                 breaks=bk1,
                 col=col,
                 sepwidth=c(0.4,0.4),
                 sepcolor="purple",
                 colsep=0:ncol(mat), ## changed
                 rowsep=0:nrow(mat)) ## changed

# Look at lwid and define a new one to use
hm1$layout$lwid
# [1] 1.5 4.0
my_lwid <- c(1.0, 4.5)

## call with altered lwid
hm2 <- heatmap.2( mat, 
                  key=FALSE, 
                  trace="none",
                  ColSideColors=colorside,
                  cexRow=0.6,
                  breaks=bk1,
                  col=col,
                  sepwidth=c(0.4,0.4),
                  sepcolor="purple",
                  lwid = my_lwid,     ## added
                  colsep=0:ncol(mat),
                  rowsep=0:nrow(mat)) 
hm2$layout$lwid
```

Please, let me know whether this is what you wanted.

Comment: thank you, however what i notice is that when i increase sepwidth it just takes a space from next column/row, so it does not really move columns/rows but takes this space from next column or row

Comment: I think this kind of behaviour is built in. What you could do is work with `lwid` which defines the width of the parts in the graph. This way, you can increase the proportion of the horizontal space taken by the heatmap (as opposed to the rows dendrogram).